# AppEngine "Task size too large" exceptions

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Suddenly, in last 2-3 days I started to get this "Task size too large" exception on GAE. Notice that task spends only 4 secs and the exception is raised after execution. What means "task size too large" on this context? My app was not changed, so I suppose that something changed on GAE.

2014-09-06 09:11:34.350 /job/cicloEmp?idEmpresa=748002 500 **4140ms** 0kb AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)

I 2014-09-06 09:11:30.428
[s~noxxonsat-nxnet/v2400b.378334396813169640].: Processando ...

I 2014-09-06 09:11:34.339
[s~noxxonsat-nxnet/v2400b.378334396813169640].: Fim

**W 2014-09-06 09:11:34.348
/job/cicloEmp
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Task size too large**
    at com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.QueueImpl.fillAddRequest(QueueImpl.java:380)
    at com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.QueueImpl.validateAndFillAddRequest(QueueImpl.java:271)
    at com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.QueueImpl.addAsync(QueueImpl.java:520)
    at com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.QueueImpl.addAsync(QueueImpl.java:491)
    at com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.QueueImpl.addAsync(QueueImpl.java:456)
    at com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.QueueImpl.add(QueueImpl.java:448)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.DeferredDatastoreSessionStore.saveSession(DeferredDatastoreSessionStore.java:62)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SessionManager$AppEngineSession.save(SessionManager.java:159)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:41)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, it was a deferred task for some requests.

Disabled async-session-persistence propertie on appengine-web.xml.

```
<!--     <async-session-persistence enabled="true" /> -->
```